# FancyBox Jquery open

Tags: jquery, fancybox

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  
 $(".link").fancybox({
  scrolling: 'yes'
    });  
 
 
});
```

I have this code which works, but i'm loading content dynamically. That content does not work on the jQuery code. So I tried this

```js
$(document.body).on('click', '.link' ,function(){
  
 $(".link").fancybox({
  scrolling: 'yes'
    });  
 
 
});
```

But this does not work, the link opens like a regular link.

Any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean dynamically? through ajax?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside jquery.fancybox.js I needed to change the setting of scrolling to yes.

```
        scrolling : 'yes',
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you should extend a little bit your callback.
Need to stop default behaviour of hyperlink and after that open fancybox

My idea is something like this:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.link' ,function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    $(".link").fancybox({
        scrolling: 'yes'
    });     
});
```

Hope this will do the job for you Jason
Good luck

Comment: Fantastic! That works. Never thought about that. i really appreciate you help.